# Python Pandas aggregating whitespace-separated values in text field

Tags: python, pandas, whitespace, text-processing

I have a dataframe like this:

```
0      A\nA\nA
1      na\nB|D|E|F|G|H\nB|D|E|F|G|H
2      B\nB|C\nB
3      na\nna\nna
```

And I would like to aggregate the values by highest count :

```
0      A
1      B|D|E|F|G|H
2      B
3      na
```

I assume I should delimit the column first by '\n' so I am using

```
df = pd.DataFrame([ x.split('\n') for x in df.tolist()])
```

So I get:

```
       0            1               2
0      A            A               A
1      na           B|D|E|F|G|H     B|D|E|F|G|H
2      B            B|C             B
3      na           na              na
```

How can I merge the columns next to get the desired output?

Thanks.

Comment: So your text column is whitespace-separated. Do you have an upper bound N on the max number of items? You could have just read it in/transformed it as N separate columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) with `most_common`:

```
from collections import Counter

df = pd.DataFrame([Counter(x.split('\n')).most_common(1)[0][0] for x in df.tolist()])
print (df)
             0
0            A
1  B|D|E|F|G|H
2            B
3           na
```

Another solution with [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and apply [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df = df.str.split('\n', expand=True).apply(lambda x: pd.value_counts(x).index[0],axis=1)
print (df)
0              A
1    B|D|E|F|G|H
2              B
3             na
dtype: object
```

**Timings**:

```
In [238]: %timeit (pd.DataFrame([Counter(x.split('\n')).most_common(1)[0][0] for x in df.tolist()]))
1000 loops, best of 3: 197 µs per loop

In [239]: %timeit (df.str.split('\n', expand=True).apply(lambda x: pd.value_counts(x).index[0],axis=1))
100 loops, best of 3: 2.33 ms per loop


In [241]: %timeit (pd.DataFrame([ x.split('\n') for x in df.tolist()]).mode(1))
100 loops, best of 3: 2.32 ms per loop
```

Larger `DataFrame`:

```
#len (df) = 40k

from collections import Counter
df = pd.Series(['A\nA\nA','na\nB|D|E|F|G|H\nB|D|E|F|G|H','B\nB|c\nB','na\nna\nna'])
#print (df)
df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
In [331]: %timeit (pd.DataFrame([Counter(x.split('\n')).most_common(1)[0][0] for x in df.tolist()]))
1 loop, best of 3: 257 ms per loop

In [332]: %timeit (df.apply(lambda x: Counter(x.split('\n')).most_common()[0][:][0]))
1 loop, best of 3: 282 ms per loop

In [333]: %timeit (pd.DataFrame([ x.split('\n') for x in df.tolist()]).mode(1))
1 loop, best of 3: 9.18 s per loop

In [334]: %timeit (df.str.split('\n', expand=True).apply(lambda x: pd.value_counts(x).index[0],axis=1))
1 loop, best of 3: 15.7 s per loop
```

Comment: That does it. Thanks!

Comment: Since we're all about speed, using `apply` instead of the list comprehension adds a ~30% improvement over your best solution: `df.apply(lambda x: Counter(x.split('\t')).most_common()[0][:][0])` (152µs per loop vs. 226 on my laptop).

Comment: @jodoox - maybe use small df, for larger  this solution is a bit slowier.

Comment: @jodoox - I add timings for larger `df`

Comment: super, no problem. ;)

Answer (score 1):

`pd.DataFrame.mode`gives the expected output when applied on `axis=1`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_clipboard()
df.mode(1)
```

Returns:

```
0
0   A
1   B|D|E|F|G|H
2   B
3   na
```